# Django Gunicorn Long Polling

Tags: python, django, event-handling, gunicorn

Is using Django with gunicorn is considered to be a replacement for using evented/async servers like Tornado, Node.js, and similar ? Additionally, Will that be helpful in handling long-polling/cometed services?

Finally, is Gunicorn only replacing the memory consuming Apache threads (in case of Apache/mod-wsgi) with lightweight threads, or there are an additional benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gunicorn by default will spawn regular synchronous WSGI processes. You can however tell it to spawn processes that use gevent, eventlet or tornado instead. I am only familiar with gevent which can certainly be used instead of Node.js for long polling.

The memory footprint per process is about the same for mod_wsgi and gunicorn (in my limited experience), but you get more bells-and-whistles with gunicorn. If you change the default worker class to gevent (or eventlet or tornado) you also get a LOT more performance out of each process.

Comment: By performance I mean the ability to handle requests. This is true for most workloads since they are IO-bound and therefore friendly to eventlets / greenlets and such.

Comment: So you say that using Gunicorn only is similar to Apache/mod-wsgi deploment in terms of thread per request, but when utilizing gevent,eventlet, or Tornado in the worker class, we make them green threads, by the power of those async/non-blocking io servers, is that what you mean?

Comment: One more thing I want to it to be clarified if you don't mind, how Django-Gunicorn-gevent be utilized in long-polling events, will that be outside the request/response cycle of Django (and all similar synchronous frameworks)?

Comment: What I'm saying is that given 4 worker processes, the memory footprint is about the same regardless of if you use Gunicorn or mod_wsgi. The difference is that each mod_wsgi worker process can only handle one request at a time while each Gunicorn worker process (using gevent worker class) can handle many simultaneous requests (if the workload is greenlet friendly = non-blocking).

Comment: As far as long polling goes you can handle that using the regular request/response cycle of Django if you monkey-patch your application (I think Gunicorn does that automatically for gevent worker class). It scales almost as well as callback-based frameworks like Node.js while maintaining a very easy-to-understand code flow.

Comment: You can just wait for an event inside your view before constructing the response to the client. Gevent comes with its own synchronization primitives (like events and queues) making it easy to write code that waits for other parts of the application to process/generate data.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I see your point. +1 for your consecutive answers :))